# Expressing Sets as Regular Expressions

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> **1.** *The set of strings ending in 00 and not containing 11.*
>
> **2.** *The set of strings with every 1 followed by two 0's*

For each problem I have a few solutions, but I'm not sure which solution most accurately describes each problem.

1. $0^*(10 \cup 0)^*00$ or $(10 \cup 0)^*00$ or $\{0^*10\}^*00$

EDIT: I believe a more accurate solution would be $(10 \cup 0)^*(\lambda \cup 1)00$

I feel like the second solution is the most accurate, and I believe it is a correct solution to the problem. I don't think the third solution actually works because it does not accept the string consisting of all $0$'s, it was just an idea that I had.

2. $0^*(100 \cup 0)^*$ or $(100 \cup 0)^*$ or $\{0^*100\}^*$

Again I feel like the second solution is the most accurate representation, and again the same problem with the third solution.

So, my question is: How would you choose to represent each set using regular expressions? How accurate are my solutions?

I would appreciate to see how some of you approach this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: I think 1. does not match 100.

Comment: @miracle173 Yeah, I noticed it doesn't match anything ending with 100. I am thinking of an alternative solution, thanks for your input!

Comment: Can you explain what is λ?

Comment: Just the empty string, I think it can also be displayed as $\epsilon$.

Comment: Why do you need this? I means 1 can appear at this position. he usual regular epression syntax is 1? for this.

Comment: But maybe this is not availible in your syntax.

Comment: From adding $(\lambda \cup 1)$ you can now include the strings that end in 100. I added the $\lambda$ because, for example, say you have the string 101000. To get this string you take 10 twice from $(10 \cup 0)^*$, then you take the empty string from $(\lambda \cup 1)$, and finally you concatenate the 00. If the $\lambda$ wasn't included in this particular solution you would have to take the 1 every single time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following will work

1.) $(10 \cup 0)(10 \cup 0)^*0$

2.) $(100 \cup 0)^*$

Your pattern $(10 \cup 0)^*(\lambda \cup 1)00$ is matches the same string as my pattern $(10 \cup 0)(10 \cup 0)^*0$:

$$(10 \cup 0)^*(\lambda \cup 1)00= (10 \cup 0)^*((\lambda \cup 1)0)0 \tag{eq1}$$
but 
$$(\lambda \cup 1)0=(\lambda 0 \cup 10)= ( 0 \cup 10)$$

So 
$$(\text{eq1})= ( 0 \cup 10)^* ( 0 \cup 10)0 \tag{eq2}$$

But

$$( 0 \cup 10)^* ( 0 \cup 10)=( 0 \cup 10)( 0 \cup 10)^*$$
so
$$(\text{eq2})=( 0 \cup 10)( 0 \cup 10)^*0$$

By 
$$(0 \cup 10)0=(00\cup 100)$$
you can derive
$$(\text{eq2})=(0 \cup 10)^*(00 \cup 100) \tag{eq3}$$
(eq3) is the pattern I like most.

Comment: I made an EDIT for my part 1 solution. Of the solution you provided for problem 1 and the one I modified into my opening post, do you think either solution is more "accurate" or do you think they both represent the language adequately?

Comment: I don't know what means 'more' accurate: Either it is accurate or it is not.  My regular expressions match exactly that what is required.  Your regexp in 1. don't match 100

Comment: I suppose I am just looking for the solution that most clearly represents the problem. Also, I believe my edited solution $(10 \cup 0)^*(\lambda \cup 1)00$ includes the string 100.

Comment: I missed your edit. I think wil match all required string, but I will heck this. But the three other patterns are wrong. If the regular expression is correct, it is unclrear what means "more accurate". You must define some measure for accuracy. One possibility is to count the number of characters in a pattern string and say a pattern is more accurate ithan another pattern if it needs less characters. (10∪0)*(λ∪1)00 has length 14, my pattern (10∪0)(10∪0)*0 hs length 14, too so both have the same accuracy if we use this accuracy metric

Comment: @blues5938 I think more important than thinking about "accurracy" is to think how prove that a regular expression exactly represent a given set of strings , e.g. your setof strings defined by 1. or your set of string given by 2.